# using jquery cookie plugin append to this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm having trouble getting the code to work with only appending to ol that was clicked....right now its appending to all of the ol's

heres the fiddle im trying to work with
http://jsfiddle.net/Xg36L/6/

heres the html

```
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
<button class="btn2">Append list item</button>
<button class="btn3">Clear Cookies</button>
<button class="btn4">Show Cookies</button>
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
<button class="btn2">Append list item</button>
<button class="btn3">Clear Cookies</button>
<button class="btn4">Show Cookies</button>
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
<button class="btn2">Append list item</button>
<button class="btn3">Clear Cookies</button>
<button class="btn4">Show Cookies</button>
<ol>
    <li>List item 1</li>
    <li>List item 2</li>
    <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
<button class="btn2">Append list item</button>
<button class="btn3">Clear Cookies</button>
<button class="btn4">Show Cookies</button>
```

here is the js

```
$("ol").append($.cookie("listItem"));
$(".btn2").click(function () {
    var newLi = $("<li class='new'>Appended item</li>").appendTo("ol");
    $.cookie("listItem", (($.cookie("listItem") ? $.cookie("listItem") : '') + newLi.clone().wrap('<div />').parent().html()));
});
$(".btn3").click(function () {
    $.removeCookie('listItem');
    $("li.new ol").remove();
});
$(".btn4").click(function () {
    alert($.cookie("listItem"));
});
```

Comment: The `id` attributes must be unique.

Comment: will changing it to classes fix my problem?

Comment: It would make it valid for starters.

Comment: ok i changed it to classes

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
$(".append-btn").on("click", function() {
   var newLi = ...
   $(this).siblings("ol").append(newLi);
});
```

The duplicate `id` attributes is not valid. Change your selector to classes instead then `$(this)` will give you the specific button you clicked.

**Edit**  Actually, you'll need more html markup to give your javascript some hint as to where to insert.

One option is to wrap your sets of lists and buttons in a `div` or `span`. Then the above code will work.

```
<div>
    <p></p>
    <ol>...</ol>
    <button class="append-btn">Append</button>
    <button class="clear-btn">Clear</button>
    <button class="show-btn">Show</button>
</div>
```

Another option is to give unique `id`s to your lists.

```
<ol id="list1">...</ol>
<button class="append-btn" data-id="1">Append</button>

$(".append-btn").on("click", function() {
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    $("#list" + id).append(newLi);
});
```

Comment: there all going to have the same class name since its an index page on a rails site that gets automatically generated when the user adds a new page

Comment: i guess what im having a problem with is that when i refresh the page on my fiddle it appends to all of the ol lists........I need to create a unique cookie for each list heres the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Xg36L/13/

Comment: Yes, it looks like you need separate cookies. Also, you have too many appends. You have `var newLi = ...appendTo("ol")` then later `.append(newLi)`.

Comment: would you know how to create a separate cookie for each element with the same class name and same event handler

Comment: It seems the you need to solve the problem of identifying and differentiating your lists. If you are using a for loop to initially write out your html then you'd have a natural index.